# WPF - Focus issue with DatePicker on date select

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

After Selecting the Date from the Calendar, i was tend to move the focus to next control in the form. I tried with `Date Selection changed event` and `Calender closing event` but the focus was retained in the `DatePicker Textbox`.

```
MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

this is the code to move focus to the next control in the form. Allways this method return `True` but still the focus is not moved. How do achieve my requirement.

Comment: what is your next control..? button?

Comment: it might anything.. say a `Textbox`

Comment: Please mention the reason for down vote..

Comment: @Sankarann, seconded.  I am puzzled by the downvote as this issue is affecting me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ((UIElement)e.OriginalSource).MoveFocus(new 
TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Comment: In which event can i use for this?

Comment: try on Date Selection changed event

Comment: if you know the name of the control you want to focus on you can use Focus() method. Like textbox.focus()

Comment: No.. It cannot be limited with particular form to know the next control's name.. it need to be generic... \